# Ruby On Rails Relationships - One to Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational

I'm a beginning to ROR, but here's what I'm trying to achieve. I have two items I want to associate: matters and people. Each matter can have many people. That is, I want to create people and matters separately and later be able to link them.

For example, I may create:
Bill Clinton
Barack Obama

I may create the matters:
Global warming
War on terror

I want to be able to associate the users Bill Clinton AND Barack Obama to BOTH matters. Can someone point me to a tutorial that can show me how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I think `has_and_belongs_to_many` is used less and less by the RoR community now. While still supported, I think it is now more common to have an intermediate model (in your case something like `PoliticianMatter`) to join your `Politician` and `Matter` models.

Then your `politician_matter` table will have a PK, a `politician_id` and a `matter_id`.

Then you have

```
class PoliticanMatter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :politician
  belongs_to :matter
end
```

The advantage of this approach is that if there ever need to be future properties of the politician -> matter relationship (e.g importance, date of last occurrence) you have a model which affords this - `has_and_belongs_to_many` would not support the addition of these extra properties.

You can also access the many to many relationship directly from the Politician and Matter models like this

```
class Politician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :politician_matters
  has_many :matters, :through => :politician_matters
end

class Matter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :politician_matters
  has_many :politicians, :through => :politician_matters
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a many2many relationship between these two entities.

- A matter can be studied by many people
- A person can studie several matters

Rails uses the `has_and_belongs_to_many` helper to do that. You'll find more about that in the documentation and many many blog posts!

[has_and_belongs_to_many helper](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M001888&name=has_and_belongs_to_many)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Politician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :politicians
end
```

What you need are 3 tables: 
`politicians, tasks` and `politicians_tasks` (having the two columns `politician_id` and `task_id`, no primary key)

Hope this helps
Seb