# Intermediate model to join two seperate models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, many-to-many

I am trying to create an intermediate model between two models that I'd like to have a many to many relationship. I am creating an atypical book checkout project and have two models setup **Book** and **Person**. I'd like to setup an intermediate model **BookCheckOut** to track OutDate and ReturnDate.

[Dan Singerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43965/dansingerman) provided what looks like the answer I am looking for to the question [Ruby On Rails Relationships - One to Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846114/ruby-on-rails-relationships-one-to-many/846202#846202). My inexperience with out model generation and my reliance upon scaffolding are probably causing my problem. I am trying to determine how to not only generate the model but a working database migration that would accompany it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a rails maestro, but there are two ways to do it that I know of: `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`. [This article](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off) has a decent overview of how. I suspect you would want to use `has_many :through` so you can access the data in the join table cleanly.

To generate the intermediate model you would do something like:

```
script/generate model checkouts person_id:int, book_id:int, checked_out:date, returned:date
```

In your Book model you would add (does Rails know Person --> "People"? I'm guessing yes):

```
has_many :people, :through => :checkouts
has_many :checkouts, :dependent => true
```

In your Person model you would add:

```
has_many :books, :through => :checkouts
has_many :checkouts, :dependent => true
```

In your Checkout (sorry, I renamed it from your example) model, you would add:

```
belongs_to :person
belongs_to :book
```

Use caution with my examples - I am going from memory.

Comment: Great article, it certainly explains the options. That said if I choose *Join Model: Rich Associations* how do I go about generating the model and database migration? Do I just generate a model containing the ids of the book and person tables. Add the belongs_to :XXXXX to my intermediate model and the has_many :XXXXX to the others?

Comment: I was getting errors when I had the :dependent => symbol added. I removed it and was able to get the application to work. What is the intention behind the :dependent => ?